# Realtek ALC892 not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers

I have installed Windows 8 on a machine with an Asus M4A88TD-M/USB3 motherboard which has an ALC892 sound chip. I can't seem to get the sound chip to work correctly. I've installed the latest driver 2.70 and the audio devices in the device manager look like this:

[image: device manager]

The upper device uses the Realtek driver but the two lower once use a Microsoft default driver. I've tried to install drivers for the two lower devices manually but there are no compatible ones among the downloaded Realtek drivers (At least Windows claims so).

Anyway now the sound settings look like this:

[image: Sound]

You can see that the Realtek device is missing. Also the Realtek Soundmanager doesn't seem to work correctly:

[image: Soundmanager]

The onboard sound is activated in BIOS and works just fine on the Ubuntu I've installed in dual boot.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remove asus drivers - auto detect in w8 works fine

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thats why I installed the Asus/Realtek drivers in the first place.

Comment: Are you running "Realtek Audio Driver V6.0.1.6699 for Windows 8 32bit & 64bit." drivers from here? http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A88TDMUSB3/#download

Comment: The download page I visited looked different but the file is the same. It was the first one I've tried. After that I tried the 2.70 directly from Realtek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was kind of stupid though. I tried to setup the sound properties using remote desktop all the time. What I didn't know was, that it obfuscates the local device and creates it's own device to pass all sound through to the client. That's why the two devices are called remote audio. I noticed it when I tried connecting with another RDP Client where sound was disabled. Suddenly the two device were gone and the Sound options showed that no device was available.

Used a mouse and a keyboard locally now and it seems that everything was fine all along :-)